# Is this the right formkit configuration?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import { plugin, defaultConfig } from "@formkit/vue";
import "./assets/tailwind.css";
import "aos/dist/aos.css";

createApp(App).use(plugin, defaultConfig).mount("#app");
createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app");
```

I am new to Vue. I only started 2 weeks ago and I am having a problem installing Formkit. I followed the installation instruction and when I try to call it in my code it doesn't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code :

```js
createApp(App).use(plugin, defaultConfig).mount("#app");
createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app");
```

is creating two app instances mounting them to the same node. to register plugins you should create the app instance `createApp(App)` then chaine the `use` method :

```js
createApp(App).use(plugin, defaultConfig).use(router).mount("#app");
```

Comment: how about AOS animations in the main.js file how would you add that because it has a render

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I want to add the code but it won't appear well.